# DAO class declared in ApplicationContext (Spring)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, dao

I have been looking into some existing code of the company I am with and what i see is applicationContext.xml file has UserDAO class declared as a bean which is fine but in the DAO class itself getFromApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) has been declared which returns the instance of DAO class itself. I am unable to understand where this method gets called, who is calling it. DAO class is extending HibernateDaoSupport class 
How do I know that I have to create this method in my class because if i delete it, compiler in eclipse doesn't complain. What I am trying to say is there should be an interface or abstract class which will force me to write this method.

```
public static UserDAO getFromApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) {
    return (UserDAO) ctx.getBean("userDAO");
}
```

Please anybody who can explain a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you should not have a reference to the application context, especially in something so trivial as a user dao.

Some tips on finding the usage:

- use eclipse "Call hierarchy" (CTRL + ALT + H) to see where is the method called
- Use right click -> References -> Project to see where the class is used

If it is not used, and there is no compilation problem, and there is nothing special in the xml config (like `factory-method`) - delete it.

Comment: with CTRL+ALT+H i found out that getBean(String) from org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory is calling this method. But why it's still a mystry. Because GlobalDataAceess class is using the UserDAO bean injected into it. GlobalDataAccess class is also declared as a bean in applicationContext and in Controllers we are calling GlobalDataAccess to get DAOs where we call methods on them. So where Beanactory is playing role by calling this mystry method.

Comment: does the DAO implement some interface?

Comment: I really don't see how the getBean method of Spring could call this method, especially without using reflection. I doubt Spring has your UserDAO class as dependency.

Answer (score 1):

If this method isn't used anywhere, I think you may safely delete it. It doesn't look like some method automatically called by Spring. Instead, it looks like a utility method to get an instance of the UserDAO from the application context.

This method is useful, because it avoid hard-coding the name of the bean everywhere, but it should generally be avoided, because the whole point of Spring is to use dependency injection, and thus to avoid bean lookups like this. The application context could be used to get some root object once, at startup. But all the other beans should be injected.